# System crashed - After reboot logs contain "^@"

Tags: linux, debian, server-crashes, crashlytics

I mentioned that my linux-server crashed suddenly without any warning.

In the syslog the following is shown:

```
Sep  1 15:13:47 example kernel: [4514929.741761] Firewall: *UDP_IN Blocked* IN=vmbr0 OUT= MAC=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:0c:c4:7a:77:38:28:08:00 SRC=123.123.123.123 DST=255.255.255.255 LEN=173 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=47121 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=17500 DPT=17500 LEN=153
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^$
Sep  1 15:17:50 example systemd-modules-load[817]: Module 'fuse' is builtin
Sep  1 15:17:50 example systemd-modules-load[817]: Inserted module 'vhost_net'
Sep  1 15:17:50 example hdparm[856]: Setting parameters of disc: (none).
Sep  1 15:17:50 example systemd-fsck[1015]: /dev/sda3: Journal wird wiederhergestellt
Sep  1 15:17:50 example systemd-fsck[1015]: /dev/sda3: sauber, 314/62592 Dateien, 40617/250112 Blöcke
```

But what does the `^@` mean?

Comment: The thing is that the syslog-daemon crashed with the rest of the system, I guess 15:13:47 was about the time of the crash.
Actually this could indicate a hardware error, as NUL byte floodings often occur with memory errors or, less likely with a software error in the OS. Can you please provide more information like linux distribution, specifics and kernel version?

Answer (score 2):

The caret '^' denotes a control character, '^@' is just the caret notation of the NULL byte.

Comment: Thanks a lot. What does this mean for my problem? Why are NULLs saved to the log?